# Center an image in main content while having a fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I have a sidebar navigation, and I'm trying to center an image in the main content (everything but the sidebar), but nothing I try works.

How can I center an image in the main content of my site, while having a fixed sidebar, where the image will stay centered even if I resize the page (make the site full screen, or half screen, etc.)?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the code that you have attempted so that we can see where things are going wrong for you?

Comment: Check out [ask] and [help] for some helpful info.

Comment: Provide the html and css you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set these styles for the image:

```
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
```